# How do I quote a column in a dataframe that has a period?

Tags: python, matplotlib, dataframe

I could not find a particular way to phrase this into a google search that returned any solid results so asking StackOverflow. Would appreciate the help all!

I am using a CSV file, `Iris`, in Python to do some basic matplot plotting. Within `Iris`, I am looking to reference a particular column called `Petal.Length`.

Normally, for any other column, like `Species`, I would use `Iris.Species` to call that particular column. However for `Petal.Length`, there is already a period inside meaning I cannot use `Iris.Petal.Length`. What is the proper syntax to call a column that already contains a period? Thanks all.

Comment: A runnable  example would help

Answer (score 0):

You can use the indexing notation: `Iris['Petal.Length']`.  Using `.` (as in `Iris.Species`) only works if the column name is a valid Python identifier, but `[]` always works, even if the column name contains spaces or other symbols.

Comment: when you use indexing notation, don't you lose the ability to use brackets afterwards for retrieving items in that column? `foo[0]` <- this kind of notation.

i.e. `People.Jobs['Manager']` will pull all rows from the table People where the Jobs column equals Manager. If you had `People.[Job.Role]['Manager']` that no longer works correct?

Comment: @MichaelHwang: `People.Jobs['Manager']` will not pull all rows where the Jobs column equals Manager, so I'm not sure what you're getting at there.